# Cannot install face_recognition or dlib on AWS linux

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, cmake, dlib

When i run
pip install face_recognition (or pip install dlib)
i get this error:

Installing collected packages: dlib, face-recognition-models, face-recognition
Running setup.py install for dlib ... error

running install
running build
running build_py
package init file 'tools/python/dlib/**init**.py' not found (or not a regular file)
running build_ext
Building extension for Python 3.7.15 (default, Oct 31 2022, 22:44:31)
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake /tmp/pip-install-ahft03in/dlib/tools/python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/tmp/pip-install-ahft03in/dlib/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release'
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (project):
No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

Answer (score 0):

you need certain dependencies to do this installation perfectly

You can use this as a guide : https://www.smcarlson.com/2019/02/24/installing-dlib-on-aws-lambda/